# Writing back to a csv with Java using super csv

Tags: java, csv, file-io, supercsv

Ive been working on this code for quite sometime and just want to be given the simple heads up if im routing down a dead end. The point where im at now is to mathch identical cells from diffrent .csv files and copy one row into another csv file. The question really is would it be possible to write at specfic lines say for example if the the 2 cells match at row 50 i wish to write back on to row 50. Im assuming that i would maybe extract everything to a hashmap, write it in there then write back to the .csv file? is there a easier way?

for example i have one Csv that has person details, and the other has property details of where the actual person lives, i wish to copy the property details to the person csv, aswell as match them up with the correct person detail. hope this makes sense

```
public class Old {
 public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException
 {
   List<String[]> cols;
   List<String[]> cols1;

   int row =0;
   int count= 0;
   boolean b;
   CsvMapReader Reader = new CsvMapReader(new FileReader("file1.csv"), CsvPreference.EXCEL_PREFERENCE);
   CsvMapReader Reader2 = new CsvMapReader(new FileReader("file2.csv"), CsvPreference.EXCEL_PREFERENCE);

   try {
       cols = readFile("file1.csv");
       cols1 = readFile("fiel2.csv");
       String [] headers = Reader.getCSVHeader(true);

       headers = header(cols1,headers          

           } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       return;
   }

   for (int j =1; j<cols.size();j++) //1
   {
       for (int i=1;i<cols1.size();i++){
           if (cols.get(j)[0].equals(cols1.get(i)[0]))
           {


           }
       }

   }

}


private static List<String[]> readFile(String fileName) throws IOException
{
   List<String[]> values = new ArrayList<String[]>();
   Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
   while (s.hasNextLine()) {
       String line = s.nextLine();
       values.add(line.split(","));
   }
   return values;
}
public static void csvWriter (String fileName, String [] nameMapping ) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    ICsvListWriter writer = new CsvListWriter(new PrintWriter(fileName),CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);
    try {
        writer.writeHeader(nameMapping);

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
public static String[] header(List<String[]> cols1, String[] headers){
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String [] add;
    int count= 0;
    for (int i=0;i<headers.length;i++){
        list.add(headers[i]);
    }

    boolean c;
    c= true;
    while(c)        {           
        add = cols1.get(0);
        list.add(add[count]);
        if (cols1.get(0)[count].equals(null))// this line is never read errpr
        {               
            c=false;
            break;
        } else  
        count ++;

    }

    String[] array = new String[list.size()];
    list.toArray(array);
    return array;

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to achieve, could you give an example?

Comment: for example i have one Csv that has person details, and the other has property details of where the actual person lives, i wish to copy the property details to the person csv, aswell as match them up with the correct person detail. hope this makes sense @Thomas

Comment: FYI [Super CSV 2.0.0-beta-1](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/release_notes.html) is out now. It includes many bug fixes and new features (including Maven support and a new Dozer extension for mapping nested properties and arrays/Collections).

Comment: Thank you, i shall install this straight away, i was wondering why the java doc site had changed Any ideas why im getting nullpointer error.@ Hound Dog `code combinedWriter.write(UDC, HeadersT);` ive checked both values and they both return enteries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just be careful if you read all of the addresses and person details into memory first (as Thomas has suggested) - if you're only dealing with small CSV files then it's fine, but you may run out of memory if you're dealing with larger files.

As an alternative, I've put together an example that reads the addresses in first, then writes the combined person/address details while it reads in the person details.

Just a few things to note:

- I've used CsvMapReader and CsvMapWriter because you were - this meant I've had to use a Map containing a Map for storing the addresses. Using CsvBeanReader/CsvBeanWriter would make this a bit more elegant.
- The code from your question doesn't actually use Super CSV to read the CSV (you're using `Scanner` and `String.split()`). You'll run into issues if your CSV contains commas in the data (which is quite possible with addresses), so it's a lot safer to use Super CSV, which will handle escaped commas for you.

Example:

```
package example;

import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.supercsv.io.CsvMapReader;
import org.supercsv.io.CsvMapWriter;
import org.supercsv.io.ICsvMapReader;
import org.supercsv.io.ICsvMapWriter;
import org.supercsv.prefs.CsvPreference;

public class CombiningPersonAndAddress {

    private static final String PERSON_CSV = "id,firstName,lastName\n"
            + "1,philip,fry\n2,amy,wong\n3,hubert,farnsworth";

    private static final String ADDRESS_CSV = "personId,address,country\n"
            + "1,address 1,USA\n2,address 2,UK\n3,address 3,AUS";

    private static final String[] COMBINED_HEADER = new String[] { "id",
            "firstName", "lastName", "address", "country" };

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ICsvMapReader personReader = null;
        ICsvMapReader addressReader = null;
        ICsvMapWriter combinedWriter = null;
        final StringWriter output = new StringWriter();

        try {
            // set up the readers/writer
            personReader = new CsvMapReader(new StringReader(PERSON_CSV),
                    CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);
            addressReader = new CsvMapReader(new StringReader(ADDRESS_CSV),
                    CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);
            combinedWriter = new CsvMapWriter(output,
                    CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);

            // map of personId -> address (inner map is address details)
            final Map<String, Map<String, String>> addresses = 
                    new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();

            // read in all of the addresses
            Map<String, String> address;
            final String[] addressHeader = addressReader.getCSVHeader(true);
            while ((address = addressReader.read(addressHeader)) != null) {
                final String personId = address.get("personId");
                addresses.put(personId, address);
            }

            // write the header
            combinedWriter.writeHeader(COMBINED_HEADER);

            // read each person
            Map<String, String> person;
            final String[] personHeader = personReader.getCSVHeader(true);
            while ((person = personReader.read(personHeader)) != null) {

                // copy address details to person if they exist
                final String personId = person.get("id");
                final Map<String, String> personAddress = addresses.get(personId);
                if (personAddress != null) {
                    person.putAll(personAddress);
                }

                // write the combined details
                combinedWriter.write(person, COMBINED_HEADER);
            }

        } finally {
            personReader.close();
            addressReader.close();
            combinedWriter.close();
        }

        // print the output
        System.out.println(output);

    }
}
```

Output:

```
id,firstName,lastName,address,country
1,philip,fry,address 1,USA
2,amy,wong,address 2,UK
3,hubert,farnsworth,address 3,AUS
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea very much appreciated, im at a problem with my while loop. @Hound Dog it return java.lang.nullPointer exception Im not entirely sure why. Ive broken it down and it seems to stop at row 90.

Comment: @jbel I'm guessing you're talking about your original code. My guess is it's occurring on `cols1.get(0)[count].equals(null)` - that's not the right way to check if something is null because if the element of the array is null then the `.equals()` will throw a NullPointerException. It should be `cols1.get(0)[count] == null`.  Saying that, I think you're better off making your code look more like my example - you've got a lot of hard-to-read/redundant code in there!

Comment: Im using your code, my appoligies i get the null pointer exception error where you have [code] combinedWriter.write(person, COMBINED_HEADER); [/code] @ Hound Dog . im assuming this is user error from me

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, it seems like you have the following situation:

- File 1 contains persons
- File 2 contains addresses

You then want to match persons and addresses by some key ( one or more fields) and write the combination back to a CSV file.

Thus the simplest approach might be something like this:

```
//use a LinkedHashMap to preserve the order of the persons as found in file 1
Map<PersonKey, String[]> persons = new LinkedHashMap<>();
//fill in the persons from file 1 here

Map<PersonKey, String[]> addresses = new HashMap<>();
//fill in the addresses from file 2 here

List<String[]> outputLines = new ArrayList<>(persons.size());    
for( Map.Entry<PersonKey, String[]> personEntry: persons.entrySet() ) {
  String[] person = personEntry.getValue();
  String[] address = addresses.get( personEntry.getKey() );

  //merge the two arrays and put them into outputLines
}

//write outputLines to a file
```

Note that `PersonKey` might just be a `String` or a wrapper object ( `Integer` etc.) if you can match persons and addresses by one field. If you have more fields you might need a custom `PersonKey` object with `equals()` and `hashCode()` properly overridden.